# how to show popup when an item from listview is selected?

Tags: android, android-listview

//This is the main activity which displays the list

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    final ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.times_list);
                timeTrackerAdapter=new TimeTrackerAdapter();
                listView.setAdapter(timeTrackerAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                //how to show a popup or dialog box 
                    //my popup layout file is popup_layout_file.xml

                }
            });

         }
  }
```

Comment: Use an `AlertDialog.Builder`. There are plenty of examples on here and Google. Just place the code for one inside your `onItemClick`

Answer (score 1):

One simple example would be:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Dialog message here");
    builder.setMessage("Dialog message here");

    builder.create().show();
}
```

Read up more on dialogs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you have your own xml layout for the dialog/pop-up, here's another solution just a bit different from the one of Jarvis.

```
public class SomeDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public interface SomeDialogListener {

       void onSomethingChanged(some argument);

    }

    private static final String DIALOG_ARGUMENT_SOMEARGUMENT= "someTag";

    private SomeDialogListener mListener;

    public static SomeDialog newInstance(...params) {
        SomeDialog someDialog= new SomeDialog();
        Bundle args= new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DIALOG_ARGUMENT_DURATION, minutes);
        someDialog.setArguments(args);

        return someDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle arguments= getArguments();
        int duration= arguments.getInt(DIALOG_ARGUMENT_SOMEARGUMENT, DEFAULT_VALUE);

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_edit_duration_dialog, container);

        getDialog().setTitle(R.string.YourTitle);
        setupOKButton(view);
        setupCancelButton(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener= (SomeDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(activity.toString() + " must implement SomeDialogListener");
        }
    }

    private void setupOKButton(View view) {
        final View okButton= view.findViewById(R.id.okButton); // From layout
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something, dismiss dialog ( e.g. getDialog().dismiss(); or call listener mListener.onSomethingChanged(argument) )
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupCancelButton(View view) {
        final View cancelButton= view.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something, dismiss dialog (e.g. getDialog().dismiss();)
            }
        });
    }
```

The dialog can now be instanciated with SomeDialog.newInstance(params).show(FragmentManager, DialogTag (optional))
The class using the Dialog should also implement the dialogListener you created.

If you just need a dialog to inform the user about something you could just use a AlertDialog or just use a dialog like Jarvis suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a custom popup with your own xml layout, I recomand you to use a Dialog and use setContentView() like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PopupActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_popup);
dialog.setTitle("My first customize popup");

TextView textView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewPopup);
textView.setText("bonjour!\My first customize popup!!");

dialog.show();
```

the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPopup"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_amstrong" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPopup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="my first customize popup" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(MainActivity.this);
    String message = "Selected " + arg2+ " item";
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Click cancel button
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Click ok button
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);

  builder.setTitle("Title");
  builder.setMessage("message to show");
  builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

An activity can also be shown as a popup/alertdialog. Just create an activity using your popup layout file and add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` before `setContentView`.

Add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to popup activity in the manifest.

Call the intent from your onItemClickListener as usual

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, PopupActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps.